# How merge kendo grid footer template cells?

Tags: jquery, css, kendo-grid, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have a kendo grid. 
EXAPMLE:

```
var grid = $('[data="object-grid"]').kendoGrid({
        height: 600,
        scrollable: true,
        sortable: true,
        selectable: 'row',
        columns: [
            {
                field: 'MDATE_dt',
                title: 'Дата'                    
            },
            {
                field: 'MDATE_hour',
                title: 'Время'                    
            },
            {
                field: 'SUBJECT',
                title: 'Тема'
            }, 
            {
                field: 'TBLOBJECTS_NAMES_INFO',
                title: 'Объекты',           
                footerTemplate: '<div class="div-footer"></div>' // 
            }
        ],     
        resizable: true
    }).getKendoGrid();
```

Put value in 4th column footer. 
I need to combine all column footer.. Your options. Thanks